# Where are PIE phonemes transliterated as IPA?

Tags: proto-indo-european, ipa

Where can I find each PIE phoneme (which I don't know how to pronounce) transliterated and represented as IPA?

**Afterword:** (Delightedly but fortuitously) Searching 'Grimm's Law' on Youtube directed me to [this helpful video (explained in simple English)](https://youtu.be/VnjfHu9eJLM), at whose 2 mins 27 secs juncture, the videographer (though a linguistics student) displays and pronounces (his understanding of) the PIE consonants.

The video above motivated me to watch this user's other videos. [In this one](https://youtu.be/9jlcV7DYL3o), he explains and pronounces ALL the PIE phonemes, to his understanding.

Comment: I also did a graphic once of [how Grimm's Law worked](http://stanford.edu/~clunis/wow/grimm/) on the PIE phonemes, though there's no audio.

Answer (score 2):

You can find one list of phonemes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_phonology). These are for the most part IPA symbols, except for ḱ etc. for "palatals" and numerically-subscripted *h* for "laryngeals". This represents the standard reconstruction / phonetic interpretation, but there are alternative theories (such as that supposed *d,g* were really *t,k* and *p,t,k* were *pʰ,tʰ,kʰ*). There are non-substantive alternative transcription practices such as use of hooked-ɦ as the diacritic for the voiced aspirates -- IPA doesn't mandate use of one vs. the other, and it isn't clear whether there's a difference between *bʰ* and *bʱ* in languages -- also, the voiced aspirates can be written as *b̤*. That article gives a decent overview of controversies regarding the reconstructed phonemic system and transliteration practices.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep in mind that there are a number of hypotheses about the exact phonetic value of many of the reconstructed phonemes of Proto-Indo-European. Any modern introduction to Indo-European linguistics--even the Wikipedia article on the [Proto-Indo-European language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language)--should explain what symbols they use and how, specifically, they use them.

Off the top of my head, Mallory and Adams 2006 have a brief discussion, mainly focusing on stop consonants, which are the most debated. Forston 2004 has a more significant discussion. There are many other introductions and many important works specifically on reconstructing Proto-Indo-European phonology.

---

**References:**

- Mallroy, J. P. and D. Q. Adams. 2006. *The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World*. Oxford and New York: Oxford University Press.
- Forston, Benjamin W. 2004. *Indo-European Language and Culture*. Malden, Oxford and Carlton, Victoria: Blackwell Publishing.